# Placing icon in front of text

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to place my icon before my text, as opposed to above it, and am wondering how best to do this. I have tried using the "leading:" function but this is not working.

```
      return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding:
            EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 25),
        child: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 40)),
                Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3.5,
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                      'assets/svg/reading.svg'),
                ),
                Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 40)),
                Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.bolt, color: Colors.orange),
                Text(
                  'On-demand pizza',
                  style: theme.textTheme.body1
                      .copyWith(fontSize: 0.05 * deviceWidth),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 80)),
                Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.medal, color: Colors.orange),
                Text(
                  'Outstanding quality',
                  style: theme.textTheme.body1
                      .copyWith(fontSize: 0.05 * deviceWidth),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
```

Comment: use the Row widget

Comment: try FlatButton with icon and text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try, you can put both the icon and the text inside a Row widget as follows, and set mainAxisSize of each Row to min to center them.

```
child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, // it won't be centered without this line
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(Icons.face),
                    Text('First'),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(Icons.book),
                    Text('Second'),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

For That you can add both the Widgets inside a row widget such that they are placed side by side.

```
Row(
children: <Widgets>[
              Text(
                  'Unlimited questions',
                  style: theme.textTheme.body1
                      .copyWith(fontSize: 0.05 * deviceWidth),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center),
              Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.infinity, 
                color: Colors.orange),
           ]
         );
```

Comment: thanks - i have many different pieces of text with icons though and i have tried using a row but it is not working. I have added more code to the main question - any ideas on how to best implement the row you mention? thanks again.